# multi_match query with number throws number_format_exception

Tags: elasticsearch

I am currently migrating my search engine to Elastic Search. Let's consider I have the following records:

```
make            | model     | year  | owner_email
Crossroad       | Salem     | 2014  | john.doe@acme.com
Dutchmen        | Launch    | 1949  | bsmith@gmail.com
Four winds      | SLX Baja  | 2008  | akellerman@aol.de
```

I'd like to retrieve vehicle for a given make and year. For instance, looking for `Four winds 2008` should return the last result.

I am currently using the following request:

```
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "Four winds 2008",
            "fields": ["make", "model", "year"],
            "type": "cross_fields",
            "minimum_should_match": "100%"
        }
    }
}
```

Yet, this query raises an error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "caused_by": {
            "reason": "For input string: \"Eclipse White Hawk Ultra Lite 1989\"",
            "type": "number_format_exception"
        }
    }
}
```

And indeed, the `year` column is a `long` one, unlike the other ones, which are `text` columns.

I tried to add the `lenient` option to my query, to ignore type errors. But adding it makes the query return nothing.

Have you any other idea to make this query work? Meanwhile, as a workaround, I've updated the index mapping to set `year` as a `text` field. Fortunately, we don't need any range search based on year, for now at least.

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Why not just Add another  bool condition on year ?

Comment: What do you mean? :)

It may work if I just specify the year. Yet, we only have a single search field on our front-end, hence getting a whole string as `Four winds 1984`. The condition (year == "Four winds 1984") would never match then.

Comment: If you want to querry a long you could use a bool querry on the year field (see the answer bellow)

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `year` in a `multi_match` query as well as `range` query, you can define the year field as multi field in mapping as below:

```
{
  "year": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
      "numeric": {
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With the above change you can continue to use `year` in `multi_match` query and whenever you want to apply a `range` query on the year field then refer the `year.numeric` field instead of `year`.